# Как ставить запятые в обращениях с личными местоимениями?

Tags: пунктуация

Если человека кто-то нагло перебивает, то он отвечает (если он воспитанный):

1. Слушайте, вы! Перестаньте меня перебивать!

Если он совсем невоспитанный, то он отвечает:

2. Слушай ты, фраер! Хорош перебивать, а то...

Запятые так ставить или как-то по другому?

Comment: Serg Z., а зачем вы удалили свой ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые в первом и втором случае поставлены правильно.

Comment: Можете аргументировать?

Comment: 1. Запятая перед обращением "вы". 2. Запятая перед обращением "фраер"; запятая перед второй частью ССП, отделённой союзом "а".